# How to read out and display what users type in an input field

Tags: javascript, html

i just got started with html and wanted to create two input field where the user can put some type of text in and when he clicks the submit button a little popup shows up, displaying the info he just put in the field.

I know this is simple as buttering a bread, but i cant wrap my head around it-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showInfo()
 {

    var Größe=Number(document.getElementById("Größe").value);
    var Gewicht=Number(document.getElementById("Gewicht").value);

    return window.alert("Sie haben als Körpergröße document.getElementById("Größe") und als Gewicht document.getElementById("Gewicht")

}
```

```
<p>Körpergröße:
<input type="text" id="Größe"/>
</p>   
<p>Körpergewicht: 
<input type="text" id="Gewicht"/>
</p>

<input type="submit" value="showInfo" onclick="showInfo()">
```

Comment: Dont use accented variable names and/or id's, e.g: `var Größe`

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a start and expand on it.

```js
function showResult() {
  var el = document.getElementById('userInput');
  var val = el.value;
  if (!val) {
    window.alert("No value was entered");
  } else {
    window.alert(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<button type="button" onclick="showResult()">Show Result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry - not my langauge but..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showInfo()
 {

    var Größe=Number(document.getElementById("Größe").value);
    var Gewicht=Number(document.getElementById("Gewicht").value);

    return window.alert("Sie haben als Körpergröße " + Größe + " und als Gewicht " + Gewicht)

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use template literals in the alert. To ensure Größe and Gewicht are not NaN, I would also ditch the Number() cast.

```js
function showInfo() {
    var Größe=document.getElementById("Größe").value;
    var Gewicht=document.getElementById("Gewicht").value;

    return window.alert(`Sie haben als Körpergröße ${Größe} und als Gewicht ${Gewicht}`);
}
```

```html
<p>Körpergröße:
<input type="text" id="Größe"/>
</p>   
<p>Körpergewicht: 
<input type="text" id="Gewicht"/>
</p>

<input type="submit" value="showInfo" onclick="showInfo()">
```

Comment: Tank you very much, helped me alot and I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

Try below function:

```
function showInfo()
{
  var Größe=document.getElementById("Größe").value;
  var Gewicht=document.getElementById("Gewicht").value;
  alert("Größe "+Größe+" Gewicht "+Gewicht);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `<output for="">`

- Wrap everything in a `<form>` tag
- Add an `<output>` tag
- Assign `<output>` the `[for]` attribute and `#id`
- Set the `[for]` attribute's value to the `#id` of the `<input>` tag

> `<input id='`ID`' type='text'>`
>
> `<output id='`ANY`' for='`ID`'></output>`

Now the `<output>` and `<input>` are associated with one another which allows them to share data easier.

---

#### Reference

> - [HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) and [FormElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)
> - [`<output>` Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output)
> - [`[for]` Attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/output-element/)
> - [`classList` Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
> - [CSS `transform: scale() translate()`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)
> - [On-Event Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

---

### Demo

```js
var ui = document.forms[0];

ui.onsubmit = popUp;

function popUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ui.out.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
#out {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#out.open {
  transform: scale(3) translate(50%, 100%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  font-size: 10vw;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<form id='ui' onclick="out.value = txt.value;">

  <output id='out' for='txt'></output>

  <input id='txt' type='text'>

  <button type='submit'>GO</button>

</form>
```